# Facebook Comment ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to synchronize facebook comments with wordpress comments.

And I am wondering why Facebook comment id is different for status and object (of the same wall post). I am getting the comments via FQL, and when queried by post id, then the comment ID is of the format "279659443812183_454543377958451_3088653" (fanpageid_postid_commentid). But when queried by object id, I am getting comment ID in this format "454543377958452_3088653" (objectid_commentid).

And totally strange. When posting a comment via app, whether to "post id" or to "object id", the comment id which is returned has always the same format. This is bad when I want to compare the comment ids.

Is this documented anywhere? Can´t find it.

Answer (score 1):

It is strange - it appears facebook has just started to change the format for their comments. This may have something to do with comment threading. Some heads up on this and consistency of IDs would be helpful.

So it would seem that some areas of the system will return the the old version was:

`PAGEID_POSTID_COMMENTID`

Whereas some areas will return the new version is:

`POSTID_COMMENTID`

I'm just digging into this myself - I would have thought FB would make a bigger deal of changes to ids. Perhaps putting that on the breaking changes roadmap page would have been a start...

Comment: Yes, the comment ID should be unique. I am not sure if this is a wanted behavior. So you think the format without page id is a newer one? I discovered it´s in relation to whether you´re fql query is is searching by object id (photo, video) or post id.